# ethernet not working in Ubuntu 14.04 after I installed it along with Windows 10

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, ethernet

`lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'Eth|Net'` produces the following output in my system:

```
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet      Connection (2) I219-V [8086:15b8] (rev 31)
Subsystem: ASUSTek Computer Inc. Device [1043:8672] 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 980][10de:13co] (rev a1)
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Its a bug
Enter Ubuntu recovery mode press Shift during boot up for GRUB menu
goto Ubuntu recovery mode select root enter password

enter these three commands in sequence

```
rmmod forcedeth
modprobe forcedeth msi=0 msix=0
```

resume normal boot ethernet should work
if this works edit the file

/etc/init/module-init-tools.conf or /etc/init/kmod.conf)
to make it permanent add the line after the wile statement's ending and before end script

```
exec rmmod forcedeth
```

And add the line `modprobe forcedeth msi=0 msix=0 to /etc/rc.local`

If none of these works try

```
sudo ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off
```

I hope this helps :)